# If a moderator holds a question, does s/he get notified when I edit the question to address the hold?

Tags: support, status-completed

If a moderator holds a question, does s/he get notified when I edit the question to address the hold? Or do I need to comment in reply to the moderator that I've changed the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no notification made to any user when a question is edited.

The only thing the edit of an On Hold question does is to place it in the Re-Open queue for reviewers to assess whether the edit has been sufficient.

I think questions in the Re-Open queue are presented to non-Moderators first because there appears to be a lag before I see them.

An @reply in a comment is the best way to notify a Moderator that you have edited a question that they have placed On Hold.

The other way is via a flag, but please try using an @reply first because that way only the specific Moderator who placed it On Hold needs to re-review it.

Comment: Check if edited questions with "closed" status are sent to the queue. Almost sure they don't, but only the edited "on hold" ones. As you know "on hold" are closed questions recently asked (within a week I guess), while "closed" is older. The "closed" questions will only be sent to queue (after an edit or not), if someone casts a reopen vote.

Comment: @AndreSilva I think you are correct: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171718/215590 - thanks!